# Encoding a single key in associative array to base64

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, base64, associative-array

I am trying to retrieve user data from a SQL table where one of the columns is blob_medium. I run the SQL query properly and get the data in the php script.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)){
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $result_array['user_data'][]=$row;
    }
}
```

Now, to json_encode this data, I need to encode the data of user_pic column to base 64. For that I am trying this. But, it seems I am doing something wrong. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
foreach($result_array as $key){
      foreach($key as $key2){
            //print_r(base64_encode($key2['user_pic']).'<br/>'.'<br/>');
            $key2['user_pic'] = base64_encode($key['user_pic']);
           //print_r(($key['user_pic']).'<br/>'.'<br/>');
      }
}
```

When I uncomment the print_r statements my data is printed in base64 format but the data of the assoc array is not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're changing the `$key2` array. A temporary value created by your `foreach`loop. I myself would recommend using a `for` loop in this specific situation, because I was told to never use a loop within a loop if I can prevent it, and it makes things a lot easier to read:

```
for($i=0; $i < count($result_array['user_data']); $i++){
 $encodedUserPic = base64_encode($result_array['user_data'][$i]['user_pic']);
 $result_array['user_data'][$i]['user_pic'] = $encodedUserPic;
}
```

Comment: I'd still use a foreach, but dispense with the outer loop.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the array's `$key` and `$keys` in the for loop are copies.  If you want them to modify the original you can either do it by  specifying them to be references, not copies:

```
 foreach($result_array['user_data'] as &$key){
        $key['user_pic'] = base64_encode($key['user_pic']);
  }
```

Or by explicit index into the original:

```
 foreach($result_array['user_data']  as $index => $key){
        $result_array['user_data'][$index] ['user_pic'] = base64_encode($key['user_pic']);
 }
```

Comment: I personally feel like there's no need for a loop inside a loop. It'd be a lot easier to create a single `for` loop for this specific situation. Props for typing faster than me, though ;)

Comment: @Babydead good point, just noticed the explicit use of only the 'user_data' index in the  original result array

Comment: And I completely missed that you can keep the foreach intact by doing it your (updated) way. This makes my answer redundant, but I'll leave it for whatever case. I'll upvote yours for outsmarting and outspeeding me :')

Comment: Tried using this also, for my case this worked too. I don't know if we can mark two answers correct. but anyway, Thanks for your help.